# How can I keep python dictionary sorted?

Tags: python, dictionary

lets say I have list like this

```
x = ["foo", "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar"]
```

and I want to count number of each occurrence in a dict but I want them ordered while I am looping through the list. Like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
ordered_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0, {})
for line in x:
    ordered_dict[line] += 1
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
{"foo":3, "bar":2, "baz":1}
```

I wonder if there is someway to keep the dictionary ordered while I am looping. Currently I use **heapq** after loop

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, *by their very nature*. You have a thing named `ordered_dict`, but it isn't actually ordered (it's not a `collections.OrderedDict`). Note that you could use a `collections.Counter`; `Counter(x).most_common()` will come in handy...

Answer (score 3):

You need an OrderedDict with the "reversed" option.  You used a defaultdict instead.  These are not sorted, by design.

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

OrderedDict is usually sorted by key insertion.  If you want the dictionary sorted by value, you may want to use a Counter and then insert those entries into an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just used the wrong collection from `collections`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(Counter(["foo", "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar"]).most_common())
OrderedDict([('foo', 3), ('bar', 2), ('baz', 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
x = ["foo", "foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar"]
d = {}
for item in x:
    d[item] = d.get(item,0) + 1
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'bar': 2, 'baz': 1, 'foo': 3}
```